# failed to import numpy as np when I worked with jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter

In Jupyter, there is an `ImportError`:

```
import numpy as np
```

> ImportError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> ipython-input-1-4ee716103900 in module()
>
> ----> 1 import numpy as np
>
> ImportError: No mudule named numpy

But in Python, there is no error:

```
import numpy as np
```

Comment: Please [don't post code as images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) - post your code and error message as text instead.

Answer (score 3):

Usually this happens because your `python` is one Python environment and whatever you're running your notebook with is another. Try running `import sys; sys.executable` in both environments and seeing whether or not they match. If they don't, that's your problem: whatever `jupyter` is running in is borrowing `numpy` from the `root` environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i run import sys；sys.executable in the python environment, it displays: /usr/bin/python. but the notebook displays: /bin/python. what can i do to solve it?

Comment: I recommend installing [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and using their `conda` tooling to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

For ubunutu environment
in jupyter, run:

```
import sys; sys.executable
```

This will display the python location eg

```
/home/paul/notepad_vm/notepad_vm/bin/python
```

switch to bash shell

```
cd /home/paul/notepad_vm/notepad_vm/bin/python

./pip install numpy
```

switch back to Jupyter, run:

```
import numpy as np
```

Comment: Since you are already running `pip install numpy` again (OP said already worked in Python), an alternative is to use `%pip install numpy` **from inside the Jupyter notebook cell** where you are looking to import to handle all this. This magic command was added to insure installations occur in the environment backing the kernel underlying the notebook. There is a related `%conda install <package>` command, too. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magic command for inside Jupyter.